# C++ templated function with various amount of argument

Tags: c++, templates

I have a templated function which generates a list of a certain type. For each type the list is formed by an overloaded function. Roughly it looks something like this

```
void Process(std::vector<Type1> &vector){
}

void Process(std::vector<Type2> &vector){
}

void Process(std::vector<Type3> &vector){
}

template <class T>
std::vector<T> DoFoo() {
    std::vector<T> my_vector;
    ...
    Process(my_vector);
    ...
    return my_vector;
}
```

However now the Process function for Type3 requires a second argument, the rest stays the same. For now I have just added this argument into all 3 of the Process functions but it's ugly and inelegant. Is there a way to implement it better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option would be something like this:

```
void Process(std::vector<Type2> &vector);
void Process(std::vector<Type3> &vector, const Config& config);

template <class T, typename...ProcessParams>
std::vector<T> DoFoo(ProcessParams&&... process_params) {
    std::vector<T> my_vector;
    ...
    Process(my_vector, std::forward<ProcessParams>(process_params)...);
    ...
    return my_vector;
}
```

You'd still be able to call `DoFoo` with `Type2`:

```
std::vector<Type2> result = DoFoo<Type2>();
```

but then would need to call it with an extra argument for `Type3`:

```
std::vector<Type3> result = DoFoo<Type3>(Config{});
```